# Is zero a discrete logarithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, primitive-roots

In the book Discrete Mathematics and Its Application, it said "Suppose that *p* is prime and *r* is a primitive root modulo *p*. If *a* is an integer between 1 and *p-1*, that is, a nonzero element of $\mathbb Z_p$, we know that there is an unique exponent *e* such that r<sup>e</sup> = *a* in $\mathbb Z_p$, that is, r<sup>e</sup> **mod** *p* = *a*."
We known 2 is a primitive root modulo 11. 2<sup>0</sup>=1 and 2<sup>10</sup>=1, we can see 0 and 10 both belong to $\mathbb Z$<sub>11</sub> and it isn't unique that 2<sup>e</sup> **mod** 11 = 1 with *e* in $\mathbb Z$<sub>11</sub>.
How should I understand it?

Comment: "Unique exponent" here needs to be interpreted as "unique exponent in $\ \Bbb{Z}_{p-1}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}\ $."  Obviously, since $\ r^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $, then $\ r^{e+n(p-1)}\equiv r^e\pmod{p}\ $ for all $\ e,n\in\Bbb{Z}\ $.